Is it safe to chemically degrade stump near living beech tree?
There are 2 beech trees growing about 2 feet apart.  One is smaller and very likely started as a sucker from the older tree's roots.  The older tree has a trunk diameter of ~20 inches.  The younger is about a foot wide.
The smaller tree is cut down.  I want to help the stump rot faster.  If I cut it as close to the ground as possible then cut slots or drill holes in the top of the stump and pour in epsom salts or similar to help the wood degrade, can this harm the larger tree?

Two trees of the same species that are that close share a root system.  Even though the smaller one has been cut down it is likely the roots are still alive.
It is likely that using any chemical method will affect the larger tree.
If the stump is a foot wide renting a stump grinder or hiring an arborist is a possibility that could be less risky to the other tree as this will only take the roots out in a smaller area around.
Anytime I got a tree or large shrub stumped out it was messy and not a process with pinpoint precision.
If you really like the large tree then do nothing.  Perhaps there is a decorative element that can enhance the stump.

The larger tree is dying but is not mine and I do not want to do any damage to it.  I assume grinding the stump to ground level and covering it with fertilizer to speed rotting is safe; correct?

Stumping is probably safer but it depends if the person using it knows how to!  It is super easy to grind out a larger area than expected.
